# Error 127 g++: Command not found

Tags: c++, matlab, compiler-errors, g++, matlab-engine

I've tried to add the following lines to my makefile in order to add some MATLAB plots to my C++ routine, to set the environment variables:

```
export PATH='/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/bin':$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64:/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/gnlxa64':$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And to provide the code with the correct location for the include files at compilation time:

```
.cpp.o:
    g++ -c -DUNIX $(DEBUG) -I $(NR_DIR):/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include/ $<
$(CMD): $(OBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $(OBJ) -L$(NR_DIR) -lnr  -DUNIX -I $(NR_DIR):/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include/
```

Where I've only added *:/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include/* to the includes.

**The compilation runs normally, except that the one .cpp file I've made changes to (which is the one that requires the new includes) sends the following error:**

[image]

which sounds like I should install g++ but how could that be if g++ is run for all the other files properly and it's also working just fine compiling the original program?

**I would like to know if I am making a mistake in the compiler call and if the exports are not all right.** This is working properly on my laptop but now that I've tried to migrate the program to our school's cluster it's become messy.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you echo $PATH before g++ to make sure you haven't blown the path to dust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-I` option to `g++` does not presume a semicolon-divided directories list. This means you have to use `-I` option for each directory. Example:

```
-I $(NR_DIR) -I/APP/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include
```

Comment: I've tried this modification but I still got the error... could there be anything wrong with the $<... I'm not familiar with this syntax and just trying to update somebody else (i don't know) work.

Comment: I don't really think so. Try to `echo` the `PATH` variable one line above prior running g++ in the Makefile, perhaps it is not correct. If not yet - please update the description with the recent version of the Makefile and the error.

Comment: wherever I put the "echo" it tells me "missing separator", would you mind telling me the right way to do this?

Comment: I can try, but I cannot do this blindly. Please update your issue description with the actual code according to my hints.

Comment: I've added the makefile as an image, the error is still the same

Comment: ah... you have `export PATH...` and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your Makefile? Move them out, either to a shell script which starts the make command, or export by hands, but do not keep them in the Makefile!

Comment: Oh... what's wrong with that? I used to run it like that on my local computer and it worked... Also, how often should these be run? On my computer I needed to do so every time I wanted to execute the code which is why I ended up putting them in the Makefile

Comment: I cannot say for sure whether this is correct or not, but at least I have never seen exporting from Makefiles. You can leave it if you like, but if you need to find the root cause of your issue I would recommend to remove those two lines from Makefile.

Comment: Ok, I did and I still get the same result... I am now running a script which does the exports then runs make as you advised.

Comment: I just noticed, in the Makefile you have added the second include after $< at the line 20. It should be before $< so, that $< ends the line. That would be the second finding.

Comment: That did it!! Now I have more mistakes to work on haha THANKS FOR SHARING YOUR TIME!! Also, would you mind explaining the syntax??

Comment: You're welcome! Actually I don't have a very deep experience on the makefiles. I normally use cmake to generate them. So I am afraid to give you a wrong guidance. But I think there should be many howtos, like this for instance: https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html. Perhaps you can follow some of them just for the overall idea, and then dig into details basing on your code.

Comment: Thanks!! This is really helpful!